# Leer imagen en WEB API C#. Net - Angular sql server

Tags: c#, sql, angular, .net, server

Estoy creando una aplicacion con Angular y necesito ayuda. Tengo una api "agregarActor" que mediante un formulario de Angular, te crea el actor, el mismo te pide: Nombre, fechancimiento, biografia e imagen. La Api lee bien todos los campos menos la imagen. Por alguna razón no le llega la imagen, yo en el front end la veo bien, les dejo codigo, del front:

```
export interface actorCreacion{
nombre:string;
fechaNacimiento:string;
biografia:string;
foto:Byte;
```

El servicio:

```
public crearActor(actor:actorCreacion){ aca hago el llamado .post pasandole el actor
```

En cuanto al backend, tengo la clase de actor asi:

```
public int Id { get; set; }

public string Nombre { get; set; }    

public string Biografia { get; set; }

public string FechaNacimiento { get; set; }

public byte Foto { get; set; }
```

Asi itero sobre la tabla de sql server, para el metodo GET:

```
            while (reader.Read())
        {
            int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
            string nombre = reader.GetString(1);
            string biografia = reader.GetString(2);
            string fechaNacimiento = reader.GetString(3);
            byte foto = reader.GetByte(4);

            Actor actor = new Actor(id, nombre, biografia, fechaNacimiento, foto);
            lista.Add(actor);}
```

El metodo post, que es el cual me está tirando error, es este:

```
        SqlCommand command = new(Settings.Database.Queries.Actores.Create, conn);

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", actor.Nombre);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Biografia", actor.Biografia);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaNacimiento", actor.FechaNacimiento);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Foto", actor.Foto);
        int rows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        result = rows > 0 ? "Success" : "Failed";
```

El controlador del metodo:

```
  public IActionResult agregarActor([FromBody]Actor actor)
    {
        return Ok(Actores.agregarActor(actor));

    }
```

Debugeando, los datos que ingreso en el formulario llegan bien, menos la foto.

El error que tengo en consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La imagen se sube y se ve bien en el front, en la api me tira error. que podria ser? La foto en la tabla es de tipo binary(50)

Comment: Como sugerencia, las imágenes no se guardan en la db, lo que se guarda es la ruta en donde esta alojada, en tu caso, cambiara en el modelo el tipo de dato a `string` del atributo Foto,

Comment: Y después como hago para que me capture la imagen?

Comment: En C# puedes usar la clase `FileStream` para realizar la carga de un archivo al servidor